# php7.4, php7.4-fpm, http2, Apache, nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx, http2, php-7.4

- Can I use php7.4-fpm with Apache? Or is php-fpm really only for use with nginx? And why?
- Does php7.4 support http2? Or do you still need php-fpm? The official http2 site (http2.pro) hasn't been updated in a couple of years.
- Still worth activate HTTP2? (The latest update dates back to a couple of years ago.)
- To activate http2 I followed all the procedure described here: https://http2.pro/doc/Apache, now if I have to reactivate php (normal) how do I go back?

(The question was initially much more explanatory, but the administrators didn't like it ... they ask for it to be more focused, so let's try with only the questions.)

Comment: Quote "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.". You've got half a dozen questions here, some of which are opinion based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php7.4, php7.4-fpm, http2, Apache, nginx, I'm confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795352/php7-4-php7-4-fpm-http2-apache-nginx-im-confused)

Comment: You shouldn't be recreating the same question to avoid a closure, you should make edits to your question and request it to be reopened.

Comment: I don't want problems, tell me what you want me to do and I do it, if you want I can also open a new post for every single question, it's the same for me. But anyway, I got a reply and it also seems exhaustive. He understood what I was asking, and I understood that: yes, I can use fpm with apache, to use http2 I still have to use fpm and it is still worth using http2 ... the last question vanishes because there is no need to go back to php. Okay for me, that's what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, because HTTP server are responsible for connecting with the client, and client requests are forwarded by Apache to the [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) handler (Apache / Nginx), so HTTP2 support depends on whether your version of HTTP server supports it .
2. Same as above, HTTP2 support depends on whether your version of HTTP server supports it. In Apache, run `sudo a2enmod http2` to enable it, then Apache will be forward requests to PHP-FPM.
3. As of Apache 2.4.26, `mod_http2` is no longer considered experimental. Answer below has been updated to reflect this. Most modern browsers support HTTP2. If there are no special circumstances, enabling HTTP2 is better than HTTP1.1, but as you have followed. It is recommended to enable HTTPS at the same time, because most web browsers do not support plain text HTTP2. You can read the list of known issues at [GitHub mod_h2/issues repo](https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues) 
   to perform a risk assessment.
4. As with the first point, PHP-FPM is not directly related to HTTP2, so after you enable HTTP2, you usually do not need to make additional settings for PHP-FPM, and still work normally.